# parsing input and adding to struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strtok

I have some code that is trying to take in data from a file.  the format is like this : 9/2d 0/1s.  There could be multiple of those in the file but i need to take the first number and set it as the index to add at.  Then I need to save the next number and character as separate values.  I have some code here but it doesn't work so well.

```
    struct matrix tokens[nbrState][12];
    int *num = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while ((ptr = fgets(buf, 256, fp)) != NULL){
            ptrToken = strtok(buf, "/");
            int count = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < 12; r++){
                    if(count >= 3){
                            ptrToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
                            index = atoi(ptrToken);
                            tokens[index][r].state = index;
                    }
                    count++;
            }
    }
```

Here is my updated code.  It works abit better.

```
    struct matrix tokens[nbrState][12];
    char *tok;
    int index = 0;
    int state = 0;
    while((ptr = fgets(buf, 256, fp)) != NULL){
            ptrToken = strtok(buf, " ");
            tok = ptrToken;
            //index = strtok(tok, "/");
            for(int r = 0; r < 12; r++){
                    index = atoi(tok);
                    state = atoi(ptrToken);
                    tokens[index][12].state = state;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Yes they are all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%d/%d%c", &index, &separateInt, &separateChar) == 3) {
    // use values as needed
    tokens[index][11].state = sepatateInt; 
}
```

The loop will continue until EOF or input from the file does not match the format.

Comment: It doesn't really like using this.  It gives me "passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type" I've tried changing up my variables to make it work but it doesn't like me.  It also gave this "expected 'struct FILE * restrict' but argument is of type 'char *'"

Comment: One more thing.  I keep getting this error "variable 'tokens' set but not used"  I know I'm using but I can't get rid of that.  I'm using typedef when I define my struct.

Comment: No, if I did I commented them all out.

Comment: Wow, I should have realized that sooner.  Thank you.  That makes alot of sense.